# Attempting to run Luhn's Algorithm in C

Tags: c, cs50, luhn

So, I'm trying to make Luhn's algorithm in C, but it doesn't return the correct values when running it.

```
    //Luhn's Algorithm
    int tsum = 0;
    if (count % 2 != 0)
    {
        for (int tempcount = count; tempcount > 0; tempcount--)
        {
            if (tempcount % 2 != 0)
            {
                tsum += (cardNum % 10);
            }
            else
            {
                tsum += (cardNum % 10)*2;
            }
            cardNum /= 10;
        }
    }
    else
    if (count % 2 == 0)
    {
        for (int tempcount = count; tempcount > 0; tempcount--)
        {
            if (tempcount % 2 == 0)
            {
                tsum += (cardNum % 10);
            }
            else
            {
                tsum += (cardNum % 10)*2;
            }
            cardNum /= 10;
        }

    }
    tsum %= 10;
```

I have spent hours trying to troubleshoot and find the issue, count represents the number of digits in the card number, the rest define themselves.

I would appreciate somebody to tell me what I'm doing wrong, thank you.

EDIT: Apologies, cardNum is a long long. And I am expecitng a value of 0 for tsum when inputting any card number from [Paypal's Standard Test Cards](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/payflow/integration-guide/test-transactions/#standard-test-cards). I would also like to add, in my mind what this code should do is: using the checks for even and odd it will start from the rightmost digit and add it to tsum, every other digit will do the same. Then starting from the 2nd rightmost digit, the digit is multiplied by 2 then added to tsum, with every other digit doing the same. Then, the last line will check the rightmost digit of the current tsum and will tell me if the card is valid according to Luhn's Algorithm.

Comment: Please give us a [mcve].  In particular, what type is `cardNum`?  It better be at least 64 bits.

Comment: Note that general advice is that credit card numbers should be processed as strings, not as integers.

Comment: Line "if (count % 2 == 0)" can be safely deleted.

Comment: You can delete an entire "for" loop (and the external "if" too) if you use "if (tempcount % 2 == count % 2)"

Comment: In order to understand your code, and understand why it does not do what you expect, you should add comments. It helps a lot if you also add a short description of the algorithm (step by step) - so you can compare what you do with what you should do. If I understand your code correctly, you skip an entire step of the algorithm (if not more).

Comment: With the minimum reproducible example, you need to give the input you're trying and the expected output. The Wikipedia article version of the algorithm is both simpler and different from yours.

Comment: You might add your definition of Luhn's algorithm. The "Description" section on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) misses one step (as your code also does) which is included in the example and pseudocde implementation nevertheless.

Comment: Also: how do you know that it odes not return the correct value? What number do you provide to the algorithm, what value do you get, and what value do you expect?

Comment: @virolino i use the paypal standard test cards which should always return 0, however they do not return 0. The value I do get varies from card to card which at least means im performing some sort of function.

Comment: Did you see the `-9` in the pseudo code on Wikipedia?

Comment: @Gerhardh yes, i did see that what exactly does it mean? The sum needs to be subtracted by 9?

Comment: If `(cardNum % 10)*2;` has 2 digits, subtract 9. Just dropping part of the example is not likely to produce desired results.

Comment: @tp23: *"yes, i did see that what exactly does it mean? The sum needs to be subtracted by 9?"* - it is useless to try to write software to implement an algorithm, if you do not understand the algorithm first. So your first mistake was to not study the algorithm enough until you understood it. Before using a computer, just execute the algorithm with pen and paper, follow each step, understand what happens. When everything is clear, start your IDE and start coding.

Comment: @virolino I prefer Common Lisp to pen and paper ;) `(defun luhn-method (n)
       (mod
        (loop
          for x = n then (floor x 10)
          while (> x 0)
          for double = nil then (not double)
          for digit = (mod x 10)
          for factor = (if double 2 1)
          for y = (let ((a (* digit factor)))
                    (if (> a 9) (- a 9) a))
          do (format t "~%~a" (list :x x :double double :digit digit :factor factor :y y))
          summing y)
        10))`

Comment: @virolino i did use one of the code numbers on pen and paper, however i got it to work out without subtracting 9 from any value. Weird, maybe my math was wrong.

Comment: @tp23: or you just happened to find an exception, where you get the same number whether you make a mistake or not.

Comment: @BitTickler: That comment was not for you. For a programmer, any language is good. For someone who does not know programming at all, and who does not understand the algorithm either, another programming language will only make the fog thicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help, I was able to solve this issue as it seems I had missed a step in Luhn's Algorithm.

```
    //Luhn's Algorithm
    int tsum = 0;
    int luhn;
    if (count % 2 != 0)
    {
        for (int tempcount = count; tempcount > 0; tempcount--)
        {
            if (tempcount % 2 != 0)
            {
                luhn = (cardNum % 10);
                tsum += luhn;
            }
            else
            {
                luhn = (cardNum % 10) * 2;
                if (luhn > 9)
                {
                    tsum += (luhn - 9);
                }
                else
                {
                    tsum += luhn;
                }
            }
            cardNum /= 10;
        }
    }
    else if (count % 2 == 0)
    {
        for (int tempcount = count; tempcount > 0; tempcount--)
        {
            if (tempcount % 2 == 0)
            {
                luhn = (cardNum % 10);
                tsum += luhn;
            }
            else
            {
                luhn = (cardNum % 10) * 2;
                if (luhn > 9)
                {
                    tsum += (luhn - 9);
                }
                else
                {
                    tsum += luhn;
                }
            }
            cardNum /= 10;
        }

    }
    tsum %= 10;
```

Here, I defined luhn as the next integer to be added to the tsum, in doing this I was able to fill in the missing step by subtracting 9 before adding to tsum if luhn exceeded 9.

Comment: As I already suggested before, there is a lot of opportunity for optimization of your code - to make it both smaller and faster. Keep trying ;)

Comment: @virolino as i’m sure you can guess i’m quite the novice haha, still learning taking cs50. Right now I’m just happy to get it working, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I usually do if I "try to implement" something I am not sure about: I use an interactive language, such as Common Lisp, tinker and test interactively until it works. Then, I usually have some good template I can use to write it in a less powerful language such as C.

```lisp
(defun luhn-method (n)
       (mod
        (loop
          for x = n then (floor x 10)
          while (> x 0)
          for double = nil then (not double)
          for digit = (mod x 10)
          for factor = (if double 2 1)
          for y = (let ((a (* digit factor)))
                    (if (> a 9) (- a 9) a))
          do (format t "~%~a" (list :x x :double double :digit digit :factor factor :y y))
          summing y)
        10))
```

I did this just from reading the wikipedia page about Luhn method (the german wiki page is easier to understand because it shows a simple exampple, while being less verbose than the english version).
From your Paypal site, the first number produces

```
(luhn-method 378282246310005)

(X 378282246310005 DOUBLE NIL DIGIT 5 FACTOR 1 Y 5)
(X 37828224631000 DOUBLE T DIGIT 0 FACTOR 2 Y 0)
(X 3782822463100 DOUBLE NIL DIGIT 0 FACTOR 1 Y 0)
(X 378282246310 DOUBLE T DIGIT 0 FACTOR 2 Y 0)
(X 37828224631 DOUBLE NIL DIGIT 1 FACTOR 1 Y 1)
(X 3782822463 DOUBLE T DIGIT 3 FACTOR 2 Y 6)
(X 378282246 DOUBLE NIL DIGIT 6 FACTOR 1 Y 6)
(X 37828224 DOUBLE T DIGIT 4 FACTOR 2 Y 8)
(X 3782822 DOUBLE NIL DIGIT 2 FACTOR 1 Y 2)
(X 378282 DOUBLE T DIGIT 2 FACTOR 2 Y 4)
(X 37828 DOUBLE NIL DIGIT 8 FACTOR 1 Y 8)
(X 3782 DOUBLE T DIGIT 2 FACTOR 2 Y 4)
(X 378 DOUBLE NIL DIGIT 8 FACTOR 1 Y 8)
(X 37 DOUBLE T DIGIT 7 FACTOR 2 Y 5)
(X 3 DOUBLE NIL DIGIT 3 FACTOR 1 Y 3)
0
```

making it easy to see every single step of the algorithm and convincing yourself it is correct.

To port this to C, first we need to explore, if C has an integer type wide enough for those credit card numbers (lisp has large integers by default - one thing less to worry about in our prototype). Lisp again:

```
(log 378282246310005 2)
48.426456
```

So, we need a 64 bit variable and should be good.
Since integers in C are implementation/platform/system specific, we should use some header file, giving us the correct type:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
```

In there, the 64 bit unsigned integer is defined as `uint64_t` and if your compiler and your header files are correct for your system, using that makes sure, you do not get it wrong. The native "unsigned long long" etc. are just guesswork and not portable.

With that in place, we can simply port the code above to C:

```c
uint64_t luhn(uint64_t n) {
  uint64_t x = n;
  uint64_t sum = 0;
  uint64_t factor = 1;
  while (x > 0) { 
    uint64_t y = (x % 10) * factor;
    if (y > 9) 
      y = y - 9;
    sum += y;
    x = x / 10;
    if (1 == factor) {
      factor = 2;
    } else {
      factor = 1;
    } 
  } 
  return sum % 10;
}
```

Summary:
A proper tool set helps getting stuff done. If you don't know yet, how to use a C debugger and step through code line by line while watching the content of variables, an interactive programming language is probably easier for you for prototyping.

Comment: *"a less powerful language such as C"* - how do you define the power of a language?

Comment: Any turing complete language is...well turing complete. More powerful languages allow using higher level facilities right out of the box compared to having to start a major project to get them available. For example here, Since Common Lisp has large integers as a default data type, you need not first look up which c-library offers large integers, how to install and use it and to learn its API. In CL, you just use them. => More powerful. This is but 1 example and the major difference is, how many steps it takes to get to be able to do what you actually want to do.

Comment: But isn't it the "power of the standard library" or "the power of the distribution", rather than the power of the language? No processor provides "big integers", and the fact that the language is intertwines with the library, it does not mean that the language is more powerful. It just has better friends. I see the "power of a language" as the ability to do what other languages cannot do, regardless of the libraries.

Comment: If you would talk in terms of strengths and weaknesses, we might be able to be on the same page. No language is perfect. But when C is on the value-less side, and Lisp is the boss to rule them all... you kind of not make sense.

Comment: @virolino An oxcart has 4 wheels and some structure you can put stuff on. So does a 7 series BMW. Of course, you can apply the same line of reasoning, defending the oxcart ;)

Comment: Your example is so out of context, that it is a discussion stopper. Sorry.

Comment: C is the oxcart, Common Lisp the BMW, in case you did not see where it all connects. Your line of reasoning about "C being like Common Lisp" is exactly as my above analogy.